# Twitter Bootstrap Popover error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing some error with twitter bootstrap popover example

**HTML**

```
 <h1>Popover</h1>
 <a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover"
    data-content="This isthe body of Popover"
    data-original-title="Creativity Tuts">
 </a>
```

**Included Script Tags**

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"
src="js/bootstrap.js"
src="js/Tooltip.js"
src="js/Popover.js"
```

**My JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('example').popover();
});
```

I downloaded the following libraries:

- bootstrap.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- popover.js
- tooltip.js

But the code still does not work

Comment: You don't need to include each bootstrap js file individually if you've already included [bootstrap.js](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js).  Still, @Arun P Johny, is correct.  See this [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/VUZhL/) for a workign demo

Answer (score 4):

`example` is the id or the target element, so you need to use [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector)(prefix `#`). Your selector([element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)) looks for an element with tag name `example` like `<example ...>...</example>`

```
$('#example').popover();
```